# Get a Value from a Column after Filter is applied in a Measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power Bi - I'm trying to get a value but exclude rows that match the data in the filter.

DAX: `MS AgeTicket = IF(FILTER(Database, NOT Database[state] IN {"Closed Complete", "Cancelled", "Closed", "Closed Cancelled", "Canceled", "Closed Incomplete", "Closed Skipped", "Resolved"}),SELECTEDVALUE(Database[CLMN TicketAge]),0)`

Sample data is:

| Client | Number | Type | Engineer | Group | Open_date | Subject | State | CLMN TicketAge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bobs Burgers | SR-123 | Request | Bob Smith | Desktop | 11:56am 10/03/2023 | Test | Closed Complete | 20 |
| Bobs Burgers | SR-123 | Request | Bob Smith | Desktop | 11:56am 10/03/2023 | Test | Open | 20 |
| Bobs Burgers | SR-124 | Request | Bob Smith | Desktop | 11:56am 10/03/2023 | Test | In Progress | 20 |

Error is: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve by - SELECTEDVALUE(Database[CLMN TicketAge])?

Comment: Trying to get the CLMN TicketAge to display - it's essentially a report to show aged cases

Comment: Do you think your case will always return a single row? Can you add a screenshot of your presentation like with the slicer and visual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- FILTER() returns a table and not a value or expression that can be evaluated to TRUE or FALSE.
- Your condition matches multiple rows, so you have to specify an aggregation.

Some kind of CALCULATE() expression is probably what you are looking for:

```
MS AgeTicket = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Database'[CLMN TicketAge]),
    NOT Database[state] IN {"Closed Complete", "Cancelled", "Closed"}
)
```

The above returns the SUM of all matching rows.

Comment: Its going into a Slicer so we can filter between the times